# What is a digital common?

Tags: ground, microphone

I am working with Benthowave BII-7186 Miniature Probe Hydrophone. In its [datasheet](https://www.benthowave.com/products/Specs/BII-7186Datasheet.pdf) I have come across the following information about wiring:

[image: Wiring of hydrophone]

I am not sure what is Digital Common, and how different it is from Common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this as well: https://www.benthowave.com/products/Specs/Hydrophone%20Wiring.pdf

Common is the GND for the power; You put your battery between +VDC pin and Common.
Digital Common is the GND for the digital inputs; You connect your digital outputs to A1 and A0 and the GND of the driver to Digital Common.
Output Signal Common is the GND for the output signal; You measure the output between the Output Signal pin and Output Signal Common.

I'm guessing the Common and Digital Common is connected directly inside the instrument. But, you can't use the Common as a connection for you digital interface because its a battery terminal to which the battery is connected to. Maybe the battery is even internally housed in the instrument, so you can't eve access that pin from the outside?

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I have been actually reading that document right now. I have this hydrophone at work, but not right here, so I couldn't remember were the wires for Common and Digital Common internally connected. I know for sure that it has battery snap connector for VDC and Common, a BNC connector for signal and two more wires for A0 and A1 gain selection.
As far as gain selection is concerned, I shall connect A0 and A1 to either GND or 9V, but not from the battery?

Comment: I'm not sure that the digital inputs are 9V tolerant. You should find the spec specifying the  logic high voltage level and the recommended maximum rating. The point is, that if you connect the battery to the snap-on connector than you will no longer be able to access the negative terminal of the battery. The digital control signals would usually come from a remote controller, I suspect, and you would need to connect the sensors GND to the  GND of the controller. That is what the Digital Common is for.

Comment: If you want to fix the gain and the digital inputs are 9V (or more like 10V because of the initial voltage of the battery) tolerant, than yes, you can connect the digital common and common together and connect the digital inputs to battery + or -.

Comment: BII-1092 is the built in preamplifier. https://www.benthowave.com/products/Specs/BII-1090Datasheet.pdf - here I have found logic high and low voltage coding. As I understood for logic low I can use either battery negative or external ground. And for logic high either floating wire or battery positive?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. However, you can also use any voltage higher than 2.4V and lower than Vs to get a logic HI. So you could drive the digital input from a 3.3V logic board if you wanted to.

Comment: That's sounds great. Thank you once again for helping me!

Comment: No problemo, you can accept my answer, if you found it useful.

Comment: Also, if you have an opinion of this, I would appreciate it. It is quite a silly question, but if my datasheet specifies output voltage as roughly 5Vpp, do I consider bipolar or unipolar output of this preamp?